# Как отобразить значение value в input?

Tags: angularjs

Как отобразить значение, подставляемое из php, в input поле в качестве value?
Использую Angular JS, но такой пример дает пустое поле input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.name" ng-trim="true" 
value="<?=$user->name?>" 
ng-minlength="3" 
ng-value="<?=$user->name?>" required>
```

Т-е нужно добиться стандартного результата, если бы было:

```
<input type="text" value="Name">
```

Comment: ng-model, ng-value и value в одном месте  - уже перебор.
ng-value можно использовать вместе с <option> или input[radio]. А так вам клиентский скрипт сбрасывает value, когда пытается считать значение у модели (а оно, предположу, null или undefined). Т.е. ng-model вам тут всё портит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решите, что важнее в данном случае для вас: использование `ng-model` или заполнение `value` из серверного кода. Если `ng-model`, то вынесите заполнение формы данными в отдельный AJAX-запрос. 
Если уж очень сильно-сильно хочется использовать и `ng-model`, и иметь возможность задать значение из серверного скрипта, то установите это значение в какой-нибудь data-атрибут (например, `data-value`). Затем в клиентском скрипте считайте этот атрибут и присвойте модели.